# Current flowing through transistor with no Vcc

Tags: arduino, transistors, breadboard, tp4056, vcc

I'm trying to get a motion sensor to turn on a motor.

I use a C1815 transistor. The problem is that the motor still turns when there is no Vcc from the sensor.

The positive for the motor comes directly from the TP4056 because the sensor was not enough to power it. The output (Vcc) of the sensor does read 3.7 V, but it won't power the motor, that's why I take the positive directly from the TP4056.

The negative from the motor runs through the transistor and back to ground on the charge module.

I will include my attempt at drawing the layout of everything.

I hope someone can solve this issue for me.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Maybe you've destroyed the transistor. Or maybe the 'sensor' whatever that is (you should link a manual or schematic etc.) has been damaged. There needs to be a series base resistor. Also an '1815 is a bit wimpy to drive much of a motor. 150mA max, and motors tend to draw a lot of current when starting. There should also be a diode across the motor, though it may not be 100% necessary with only a 3V motor.

Comment: What is the sensor?

Comment: Please provide details of sensor. Also of your physical wiring. Possibly you have wired the 1815 incorrectly - the pinout is different from 'normal' NPN's. Also - motor specs, base resistor, flyback diode as pointed out by others

Comment: The sensor is HFS-DC06.

Comment: I just notice i should of wrote 'out' instead of vcc on the diagram.

Comment: @Andy - just giving a part number in the comments s not adequate. Put the information in the question and provide a link to a datasheet. The more information you provide us the better the quality of the answers.

Comment: Put a resistor 10kOhm between base and emiter.

Comment: I thought a video might explain better whats going on here... It seems like the collector and emitter are conneced regardless of current going to the base or not... Is a transistor the only thing i can use to achieve what i want to happen when motion is detected?https://youtu.be/jg5SQpljkgQ